# How do I detect a postback in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form that I pre-populate with test data though jQuery.

```
$('INPUT[name=subscription.FirstName]').val('Jef');
```

but I only want to do this before submit. What is the best way to test this?

Comment: Do you mean just http POST or **.NET** PostBack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on the server side view technology you're using. If it is for example JSP:

```
<script>
    var isPostback = ${pageContext.request.method == 'POST'};
</script>
```

Comment: Not using JSP, but a custom ASP.NET/MVC implementation. Despite that, this answer pointed me in the right direction. Using a server variable in the javascript did the trick, thanks!

Comment: Good work, but can you please post the exact ASP.NET solution so that others who are have the same problem can benefit from this topic?

Comment: i seem to be having trouble with checking the value of isPostBack
in my script ,
i'm new to jquery and in my script file(containing Jquery code) i can't  put the script tags and i can't write if(isPostback )

how would you check the postback value using jquery ?

Comment: @eran: As answered, do it in the view file (the JSP, ASP, PHP or whatever file depending on the view technology you're using) instead of a plain vanilla `.js` file.

Comment: excuse my direct question (i'm just new at this )but how would you open the dialog from the .aspx file ?
 
what i need to do is spouse to be simple i got a form that i submit 
after validation , it runs code behind , and then i wan't the 
dialog to appear and confirm that the process(to the user) as been completed and 
redirect to a different .aspx page.